# Strange settings of IOAPIC in my vmware VM

Tags: linux, apic

I am checking my IOAPIC settings in my vmware VM (Ubuntu 16.10).
    Here is what I get from my own code of dumping IOAPIC registers and
    /proc/interrupts.

```
Reg[0] = 0x00000000
Reg[1] = 0x00170011
Reg[2] = 0x00000000
Redir[12] = 2000000000000e4: vec = e4, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[14] = 30: vec = 30, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[16] = 33: vec = 33, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[18] = 34: vec = 34, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[1a] = 35: vec = 35, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[1e] = 37: vec = 37, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[20] = 38: vec = 38, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[22] = a039: vec = 39, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 1, tr_mode = 1
Redir[24] = 3a: vec = 3a, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[26] = 3b: vec = 3b, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[28] = 2000000000000a4: vec = a4, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[2a] = 3d: vec = 3d, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[2c] = 3e: vec = 3e, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[2e] = 3f: vec = 3f, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 0, tr_mode = 0
Redir[30] = 30000000000a074: vec = 74, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 1, tr_mode = 1
Redir[32] = 30000000000a035: vec = 35, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 1, tr_mode = 1
Redir[36] = 10000000000a025: vec = 25, d_mode = 0, dest_mode = 0, pin_pol = 1, tr_mode = 1

t@t-virtual-machine:~/test/process$ cat /proc/interrupts | grep -i "IO-APIC"
   0:         16          0          0          0   IO-APIC    2-edge      timer
   1:         10       4431       1099          0   IO-APIC    1-edge      i8042
   8:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC    8-edge      rtc0
   9:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC    9-fasteoi   acpi
  12:         16          0       2063          0   IO-APIC   12-edge      i8042
  14:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   14-edge      ata_piix
  15:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC   15-edge      ata_piix
  16:        218          0          0        498   IO-APIC   16-fasteoi   vmwgfx, snd_ens1371
  17:       9518      34200          0      10249   IO-APIC   17-fasteoi   ioc0
  19:         81       4252          0       2027   IO-APIC   19-fasteoi   ens33
```

These 2 outputs are different at least in the vector fields.

My own code dumps the IOAPIC registers by writing ioapic_base and reading (ioapci_base + 0x10).

Could you help me checking why there is the difference?
Thanks,
-Tao

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Shellter,
I am not quite sure that this Q is off-topic.
I want to get a clear understand of the IO-APIC registers, I found difference in my tests with the IOAPIC description.
I am not asking for tools, recommendations, libraries, or code.

Maybe I need to re-word my Q to make a clear request.
Thanks,
-Tao

Comment: You may get an answer from the community, but usually Qs not answered in the first hour or two are more likely to never be answered. I don't think this is an on-topic Q because you have not given a way to reproduce the problem. You can improve your Q by including code that readers can copy/paste into the correct environment. Good luck.

Comment: Thank shellter for advice.
How can I edit my question by providing the code you suggested?
Thanks,